# Strongly Typed ID Autogeneratation (@EmbeddedId & @GenerateValue)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Im am mightly confused right now. What i am trying to do seems very simple. I have one Entity called 'Order' with a member 'OrderId'. The OrderId has only one property which is a long. this value is what i am trying to generate using @GeneratedValue.

As a database i am using h2 right now. Whenever i try to store something i receive the following error:

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class xyz.Order
```

It's not obvous to me what i am doing wrong.

Order.java:

```
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@Entity(name = "ORDER_TABLE")
public class Order {

   @EmbeddedId
   private OrderNr orderNr;

   @Column(name = "STATE")
   private OrderState orderState;

   @Embedded
   private OtoId otoId;

   @Column(name = "customer_wish_date")
   private LocalDate customerWishDate;

   private Order(Builder builder) {
       checkArgument(nonNull(builder.otoId), "OTO ID must not be null");
       checkArgument(nonNull(builder.customerWishDate), "CustomerWishDate must not be null");
       checkArgument(builder.customerWishDate.isAfter(LocalDate.now()) || builder.customerWishDate.isEqual(LocalDate.now()), "CustomerWishDate must be today or in the future");

       this.otoId = builder.otoId;
       this.customerWishDate = builder.customerWishDate;
       this.orderState = OrderState.ENTERED;
   }

   private void changeState(OrderState newState, OrderStateChangeEventPublisher changeEventPublisher) {
       OrderState previousState = this.orderState;
       this.orderState = newState;
       changeEventPublisher.publish(this, new OrderStateTransition(previousState, this.orderState));
   }

   public void hold(OrderStateChangeEventPublisher changeEventPublisher) {
       changeState(orderState.holding(), changeEventPublisher);
   }

   public void startFulfillment(OrderStateChangeEventPublisher changeEventPublisher) {
       changeState(orderState.entered(), changeEventPublisher);
   }

   public void cancel(OrderStateChangeEventPublisher changeEventPublisher) {
       changeState(orderState.canceled(), changeEventPublisher);
   }

   public static Builder builder() {
       return new Builder();
   }

   public static final class Builder {
       public Builder() {
       }

       public Order build() {
           return new Order(this);
       }

       private OtoId otoId;

       private LocalDate customerWishDate;

       public Builder otoId(OtoId otoId) {
           this.otoId = otoId;
           return this;
       }

       public Builder customerWishDate(LocalDate customerWishDate) {
           this.customerWishDate = customerWishDate;
           return this;
       }
   }
}
```

OrderNr.java:

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@ToString
@Embeddable
public class OrderNr implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ORDER_NR")
    private long value;

    public OrderNr(Long value) {
        checkArgument(nonNull(value), "OrderNr value must not be null");
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: just don't put the single id in an extra Class.  Put ``` @ID @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Column(name = "ORDER_NR") private Long id;``` in your Order Class instead.

Comment: @frank thanks but id really like to have typed Ids for all Domain Objects to avoid 'primitive obsession'

Comment: But for a database-generated Id a Long is a perfect match, it's not like storing a telephonenumber in an Integer, or a postal code in a String or something. Therefore using a Long for a generated Id isn't an example for 'primitive obsession'.